# Определённый интеграл методом трапеции

Tags: haskell

Помогите, пожалуйста. Я полный новичок в хаскеле, учу его меньше недели.

Есть задание:

«Реализуйте функцию, находящую значение определённого интеграла от заданной функции f на заданном интервале [a,b] методом трапеций. (Используйте равномерную сетку; достаточно 1000 элементарных отрезков.)

```
integration :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
integration f a b = undefined
GHCi> integration sin pi 0
-2.0
```

Результат может отличаться от -2.0, но не более чем на 1e-4.»

Мой код:

```
integration f a b | a < b = helper f a b 0 ( (b - a) / 1000)
                  | otherwise = -1 * integration f b a
helper f a b res step | (abs (b - a)) < step = 
                       res + ( ((f a + f b) / 2) * abs (a - b) )
                      | otherwise = helper f (a + step) b 
                       (res + ( ( (f a) + (f (a + step))) / 2  ) * step ) step
```

(Оформлено немного не так, но по-другому здесь отчего-то не всё помещается.)

Валится на первом же тесте: out of memory. Хоть убей не понимаю, что сделано неправильно. Что поменять? Как улучшить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Не знаю, почему не работает Ваша функция, поэтому кину своё решение в комментарии (всё-таки это не прямой ответ на Ваш вопрос): http://pastebin.com/r6WUjR0R.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал Ваш код. Компилировал GHC 7.10.1. Ошибку повторить не удалось. Тем не менее рискну предположить из-за чего может возникать ошибка.

В случае out of memory логичнее всего предположить, что не выполняется условие остановки функции и она сваливается в бесконечную рекурсию (или цикл). Это приводит либо к переполнению стека, либо к завершению доступной памяти.

В функции helper условием завершения является `(abs (b - a)) < step`. Попробуйте убрать функцию abs из условия и выражение `res + ( ((f a + f b) / 2) * abs (a - b) )` переписать также без abs: `res + ( ((f a + f b) / 2) * (b - a) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
integration f a b | a < b = helper ...
              | otherwise = -1 * integration f b a
```

Что будет, когда a==b? (В данном примере причина зависания другая)